# jQuery Collage Plus with width and height

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build a gallery and Im using this amazing library called `jquery.CollagePlus` (https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus). I initially did not use `height` and `width` attributes. It worked perfectly.

Now I wanna try out with `height` and `width` attributes specified. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class='album-photoss'>
  <!-- - Photo.all.each do |p| -->
  <!-- = image_tag small(p), width: p.small_version_width, height: p.small_version_height -->
  <img height='150' src='http://deelay.me/3500?http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff' width='350'>
  <img height='180' src='http://deelay.me/2500?http://placehold.it/320x180/A7DBD8/ffffff' width='320'>
  <img height='300' src='http://deelay.me/1500?http://placehold.it/320x300/E0E4CC/ffffff' width='320'>
  <img height='500' src='http://deelay.me/4000?http://placehold.it/472x500/F38630/ffffff' width='472'>
  <img height='360' src='http://deelay.me/3200?http://placehold.it/540x360/FA6900/ffffff' width='540'>
  <img height='600' src='http://deelay.me/2000?http://placehold.it/800x600/ECD078/ffffff' width='800'>
  <img height='120' src='http://deelay.me/1200?http://placehold.it/400x120/D95B43/ffffff' width='400'>
  <img height='300' src='http://deelay.me/4500?http://placehold.it/300x300/C02942/ffffff' width='300'>
  <img height='500' src='http://deelay.me/4500?http://placehold.it/320x500/542437/ffffff' width='320'>
  <img height='300' src='http://deelay.me/4500?http://placehold.it/450x300/53777A/ffffff' width='450'>
  <img height='360' src='http://deelay.me/3200?http://placehold.it/540x360/FA6900/ffffff' width='540'>
  <img height='600' src='http://deelay.me/2000?http://placehold.it/800x600/ECD078/ffffff' width='800'>
  <img height='120' src='http://deelay.me/1200?http://placehold.it/400x120/D95B43/ffffff' width='400'>
  <img height='300' src='http://deelay.me/4500?http://placehold.it/300x300/C02942/ffffff' width='300'>
  <img height='500' src='http://deelay.me/4500?http://placehold.it/320x500/542437/ffffff' width='320'>
  <img height='300' src='http://deelay.me/4500?http://placehold.it/450x300/53777A/ffffff' width='450'>
</div>
```

And here is my CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).ready ->

  $(".album-photoss").removeWhitespace().collagePlus
    fadeSpeed: 2000
    targetHeight: 200
```

I am only seeing a blank page. Upon inspection  I can see that the images have been applied the following styles:

```
<img height="150" src="http://deelay.me/3500?http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff" width="350" style="height: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1;">
```

Could anyone please help me out on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Plugin author here.

You can't specify height and width. The plugin needs to have control of those in order to compute the sizes the images need in order to fit exactly to one row.

You can kind of specify height but setting targetHeight, but even that is not guaranteed. What are you trying to achieve?

Edit: misunderstood the question. In fact if you supply the image sizes in the image tag then the plugin uses that to compute the rows - rather than waiting to load all images then compute sizes http://collageplus.edlea.com/example-size-in-tag.html

Comment: Lol. Pressed Enter. Anyway, Im trying to display nearly 100 images that are quite heavy. And I dont want to wait until all images are loaded. The doc said that if I know the height and width, then the plugin will calculate the grid and reveal the images one by one after they are loaded. That is what Im trying to achieve. http://collageplus.edlea.com/example-size-in-tag.html

Answer (score -1):

wrong!

```
<img height='150' src='http://deelay.me/3500?http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff' width='350'>
```

in this line

```
http://deelay.me/3500?http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff
```

I invalid

***http ://deelay.me/3500?***

correction

```
<img height='150' src='http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff' width='350'>
```

styles are written in the sheet jquery

Comment: dude please! anyone else?